# Non-identification the class of products in the program code

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

by thanks.
I am using EF and I created a products table in my aspnetcore5 project. When I want to use the Product Class in the program code, it does not recognize this class
when I Want  to use Product Class In My code,Non-identification according to Belowe :

```
using UCI.Application.Interfaces.Contexts;
using UCI.Common.Dto;
using UCI.Domain.Entities.Products;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;


namespace UCI.Application.Services.Product.Command.AddNewProduct
{
   public interface IAddNewProductservice
    {
        ResultDto Execut(RequestAddNewProductDto request);
    }
    public class AddNewProductService : IAddNewProductservice
    {
        private readonly IDataBaseContext _context;
        private readonly IHostingEnvironment _environment;
         
        public AddNewProductService(IDataBaseContext context,IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment)
        {
            _context = context;
            _environment = hostingEnvironment;
        }
        
        public ResultDto Execut(RequestAddNewProductDto request)
        {
            try
            {
                var category = _context.Category.Find(request.CategoryId);

                produc
               
           
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return new ResultDto
                {
                    
                    Message = "خطا رخ داد ",
                };
            }
        }
        
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have a conflicting namespace in your UCI.Application.Services folder called "Product" and no `using` statement presently to this ICI.Domain.Entities.Products. I would start by standardizing the namespace to plural, so in the UCI.Application.Services, rename the "Product" folder and namespace to "Products" as well. If you don't have a Product folder then you may have had at one time and a class is still using that namespace. Do a search for "UCI.Application.Services.Product" through the code and this will help find the class with an invalid/incorrect namespace to change. You typically want to ensure namespace and class names don't overlap so Intellisense can be a bit more helpful since you are expecting it to locate the classes add the `using` statements.

Edit: Noted the namespace was in the using block..

Other culprits are a missing `public` keyword on the class definition, or an incorrect namespace in the Product class. This can often happen if class files are moved around and their namespaces don't get updated.

Comment: thanks.but i have this namespace top of the current file

Comment: ProductFeatures and ProductImage are listed so start by checking the namespace in your Product class is correct. Also ensure that the Product class is not missing a `public` keyword, this one can be easy to miss and cause head-scratchers like this.